# why does the database creates automatically null values C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, repository

I'm trying to create a program where users can book meeting rooms. The user has to select a contact from a list box and a meeting room from another list box and create the booking using a button.

I booked one room successfully but when I tried to book another room with another user. The first booking changed its contact id and meeting id, and also contact and a meeting room were created with null values.

You can see the table details in the images.
[image: Meeting Room Data view]
[image: Contacts Data view]
[image]

The code in my Reservation Repository which I'm using to create the reservation:

```
        public void AddReservation(int roomid, int contactid, string subject, DateTime starttime, DateTime endtime, int invites)
        {
            MeetingRoom m = db.MeetingRooms.First(x => x.ID == roomid);
            Contact c = db.Contacts.First(x => x.ID == contactid);
            Reservation save = new Reservation(m, c, subject, starttime, endtime, invites);
            db.Reservations.Add(save);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The code in my MainViewModel where I'm executing the process:

```
        public void CreateCommandReservationAction()
        {
            if (SelectedContact != null && SelectedRoom != null && StartDate <= EndDate)
            {
                reservationRepository.AddReservation(SelectedRoom.ID, SelectedContact.ID, Subject, StartDate, EndDate, Invites);
                ResvList = reservationRepository.GetReservations();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Select a contact and a meeting room first.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to actually debug this line by line, there's data on your database because the code is triggered to insert it, there is no magic happening here that automatically inserts data. So first, debug it line by line, and check all the object property values one by one.

Comment: @CarloLuisito when the application is closed and I run it again and create a new reservation the previous ones that i created all of their Contact Id's and Meeting Room Id's are changed and that's why it creates new contact and a new meeting room with null values. It creates as many contacts and meeting rooms as reservations I have. I don't know what caused this... still looking for it.

Comment: you need to edit your question and add the code on how you setup the relationships of the entities

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a meeting room with ID 11 nor a contact with ID 16 so the engine created those for you?

There are not enaugh details to answer your question, try at least to post us the db schema with table relationships.

Comment: When I create a new reservation the contact ID and meeting room ID of the previous ones are automatically changed and that's why it creates new contacts and meeting rooms with null values.

I don't know how to get the db schema so I can show you... still learning sorry.